# Call external API from my local machine (host) .js & .html

Tags: javascript, html, api, localhost

as this is my first post here please be gentle ;). Please be aware that I am quite new in programming so I may ask wired questions and vice versa, please acknowledge that your answers, if contain many abbreviations or mind-shortcuts might be difficult for me to grasp.

I try to call API from my local machine. I use MAC, Chrome v78, VSC.

I have the below code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
var long;
var lat;

if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        console.log(position);
        long = position.coords.longitude;
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        console.log(long, lat);

        const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
        const api = '${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/c8896cdad78b43417e8fb2969fbc5d21/37.8267,-122.4233';

        fetch(api)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json))
    });
}
```

});

Unfortunately, what I got in my console is the 404 error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/APP/$%7Bproxy%7Dhttps://api.darksky.net/forecast/c8896cdad78b43417e8fb2969fbc5d21/37.8267,-122.4233 404 (Not Found)
```

Why does it call 127.0.0.1:5500 as well? How can I omit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used a regular string (single or double quotes) instead of a template string (backticks) to replace the proxy variable, causing the ${proxy} part not to be replaced with "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/".

The browser sent the request to "127.0.0.1:5500" because "${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/c8896cdad78b43417e8fb2969fbc5d21/37.8267,-122.4233" does not start with http:// or https:// (but with ${proxy} so the request was send to the current origin, which is "127.0.0.1:5500" (where your development website is exposed).

**Solution**

```js
const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/c8896cdad78b43417e8fb2969fbc5d21/37.8267,-122.4233`;
```